# How to change authentication from SQL Server to windows in VB.NET Webservice(SQL Server)

Tags: vb.net, web-services

Web service uses SQL  Server based authentication  how to change to windows based authentication both web server & Database service resides in different domain .

Answer (score 0):

Change your `ConnectionString` to use `Integrated Security=true;`

Comment: did the following but still doesn't work not familiar with windows authentication. 1)In Windows Server created user DomainA\UserA and added to GroupA 2)IIS configured with Windows authentication but runs in DomainB 3)SQL Server 2008 configured to allow windows authentication. and created login with DomainA\GroupA –

Comment: Connection string updated with integrated Security=true also removed the UID & PWD. Webservice runs in framework 2.0 and sql server upgraded 2008 and we have new policy to use windows authentication.

Comment: What version of IIS are you using?

Comment: IIS6 runs on windows server 2003

Answer (score 0):

I believe to use Windows Authentication across domains you will need to create a trust relationship between the two domains.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773178(v=ws.10).aspx